# Netbeans for java source tab is missing

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to create a project in Netbeans using Java, but I couldn't find the Source tab. There's only the History tab there. I tried to reinstall it, and clicked on the 'Reset Window' button, but the problem is still there.

Can anyone please help me?

[image]

Comment: *View* => *Show Editor Toolbar*, you won't need to reinstall next time for it :D

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Yes, that is already selected but the Source tab is still missing

Comment: Configs are probably persisting, not sure about the path on windows where they are located. See the "About" section where they are located.